# Adding FileHandler after creating logger using dictConfig()

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to add handlers after creating a logger with a `logging_config` dict?

Specifically, I want add a FileHandler to save error output to file when a specific argument is set when running the script. I have the FileHandler set in my `logging_config` dict, but don't know how to apply it.

I thought it might be something like `logger.addHandler(logging_config['handlers']['save_error'])` but that hasn't worked.

I'm creating my logger with the following:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

This is the logging_config dict:

```
{
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'formatter': 'default',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'save_error': {
            'formatter': 'default',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/app.log',
            'mode': 'a',
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'formatter': 'default',
        'handlers': ['default'],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if specific_argument_present(sys.argv):
       logging_config['root']['handlers'].append('save_error')
    logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
    #then the rest of your code
```